# 2 VLANs on home network with shared internet connection

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I'm trying to make my home network a bit more secure by moving devices I don't fully control (a web-enabled HP printer) to a separated network. I already had some network equipment, and purchased a new "smart managed" switch (NetGear GS105Ev2) to be able to use VLANS.

The main Router1 is a NetGear R7000 (not VLAN capable), the second router is an old TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND.

The way I have set it up now, seems to work as intended, but since I'm far from a network expert I would feel more comfortable if a real expert would be able to validate the setup.

Some requirements:

- I would like 2 separate networks, that both have internet access
- The 2 networks should not be allowed to see/talk to each other
- One PC should be able to talk to both networks.

For the first two points I will include the diagram of the current setup below.  For the third point, I installed 2 NICs in the PC, one configured for VLAN1 (with default gateway), and the other with a static IP for VLAN 2, connected to Router2, and no default gateway.

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NDRQ.png)

For the setup of the "smart managed" switch, I simply defined "advanced port-based VLANs", and put port1 and port5 in VLAN1, port3 and port5 in VLAN2.  Port5 is connected to Router1 which is also providing dhcp for VLAN1 and providing access to the internet.

[VLAN config screenshot on GS105Ev2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETh5e.png)

As I mentioned, this seems to work as intended: i cannot ping devices of the other VLAN, both VLANs have access to the internet, and the 2-NIC-Pc has access to both networks.

Since my networking knowledge is very limited, can someone tell me if there are configuration issues, security risks, bad practices with this setup that I am not aware of and/or should address?

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure Router2 does not forward anything from its WAN to its LAN, as I would assume stations from 192.168.1.0/24 would still see that router (it has an IP in 192.168.1/24 as well, probably offered by a DHCP on Router1, is that it?). Assuming you're using soho routers, that's not bad. Though a better take might be to have a single routing layer, filtering traffic between VLANs.

Comment: I just made a test and devices from 192.168.1.0/24 cannot access Router2 (not the webinterface nor a ping).  I assume that this is because I connected the managed switch to the WAN port of Router2, and this router has 'remote admin' disabled (and most likely also remote ping)?  I agree with the single routing layer, but since I'm quite happy with my current R7000 I didn't want to replace it, and was able to simply add the managed switch for 30€.  Both routers are soho indeed.  Given this info, is there anything I could do better?

Comment: Can't you have 2 LAN networks on Router1 ? Mixing VLAN1 and VLAN2, both with the same 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, is a bit unusual. I'm not sure how your switch figures out which VLAN Router1 is talking to, when responding to your printer or other devices. Are you sure your printer subnet has access to internet? (though, for a printer, is it required?)

Comment: Really appreciate the feedback. I agree, my setup feels a bit 'weird' to me too, and I post this question since I'm actually surprised it works as intended. I don't think Router1 allows 2 LAN networks.  The printer needs internet access (that is the reason I did this whole change, it is one of those HP Instant Ink printers, where HP has full control, and I don't want them on my 'regular' internal network).  Both subnets definitely have internet access. Does Router1 need to know about VLANs? Wouldn't it be the switch sending traffic to the right VLAN? Apologies if this is a silly question...

Comment: I guess it's up to your switch. With Cisco/HP/Dell, you would have a "trunk" mode where packets need to be tagged with proper VLAN ID, or an "access" mode, where my switch does tag traffic with a unique VID (+combinations of trunks+access). With your configuration, I'm not sure I'ld know how to ensure R1 may talk with both R2 and LAN1, if on a same subnet, with two different VID: one of those would not have connectivity to R1. Now you're right, your switch has an ARP table. If Router1 is somehow shown both VLAN1 & 2, its ARP request might go through the "right" one? It's a bit weird.

Comment: A more usual way to wire it might have been to plug your R2 WAN port onto some VLAN1 port and R2 LAN to some VLAN2 port of your switch. Then, plug your printer device to your switch, on a VLAN2 port. Then, R1 LAN only need access to VLAN1. Assuming you have enough networking cables for this. Though if your solution works, you can stick with it.

Comment: The switch is indeed key here: R1 port on switch is defined to be in both VLANs. From a pc connected to 192.168.2.0/24, I can reach both routers (even the one on 192.168.1.0/24), but nothing else on the 192.168.1.0/24. I don't know why as it's a simple soho L2 managed switch, not a lot to configure (no trunk/access mode for example).  Plugging the printer into the switch was my preferred solution, but the printer is wifi-only, which is the reason why I use the second router (which provides wifi for vlan2).  Thank you for all the info, learning a lot...

Comment: Makes sense. Looking at https://kb.netgear.com/30919/How-to-configure-VLANs-on-a-ProSAFE-Web-Managed-Plus-Switch-with-shared-access-to-the-internet , it seems those do have access and trunk modes. In the VLAN Membership tab, for VLAN IDs 1 and 2, looking at your ports: do you see "T" (trunk), or "U" (access)? Is it possible that while your port 3 allows VLAN 2 tagged traffic (T selected), it also allows for VLAN 1 in access (U selected)? Or that the port PVID is still 1, meaning that unless R2 tags its WAN traffic into VLAN 2, then it belongs to VLAN 1?

Comment: Interesting link! Makes me worry more though, as I did it differently (using port-based VLAN, not 801.1Q) and the way it is described would not work for me as R1 is not VLAN-aware.  With port-based VLAN it does not show the config of the port. (I added the pic in the original post).  The diagram in the kb you linked is exactly my current setup: R1 in front of the switch in same VLAN as some stuff behind the switch, and then another VLAN only behind the switch.  R1 in my case has no clue about VLANs, so I think the switch must be 'really smart' to take care of everything. Does that make sense?